# How to include `TimeConstraint` in `EulerEquations`? Is there any error here?

Tags: warning-messages, date-and-time, variational-calculus

There is a complicated statement which takes a long time to compute. 
IS THERE ANY ERROR IN THE ATTACHED PICTURE? If YES, how can I include `TimeConstraint` of `Infinity` in the variational method and `EulerEquations`?

[image]

```
<< VariationalMethods`
EulerEquations[L3 , N[r], r] /. N -> (1 &)
```

It should be noted that for some calculations after a very long time, it ends up to quit kernel! Why?! is it my computer configuration or `Mathematica` bug?

Comment: Quitting the kernel almost always indicates running out of memory.  If you monitor ram usage while the command is running, you can verify that.

Comment: Unless you'r using the Wolfram Cloud, as Bill said, it's not timing out, something is going wrong. Perhaps a memory exhaustion.

Comment: You could try and (locally) reduce the `TimeConstraint` (i.e., `TimeConstraint->{tloc,ttot}`, with e.g. `tloc = 100` and `ttot = 300`; play around with different values and see if that helps). Use `Block` to modify the `Options` of `Simplify`. Hopefully it'll spit out a result before you run out of memory.